# Template argument deduction for string literals

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers, c++11

```
template<typename T>
void print_size(const T& x)
{
    std::cout << sizeof(x) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print_size("If you timidly approach C++ as just a better C or as an object-oriented language, you are going to miss the point.");
    // prints 115
}
```

This prints 115 on a recent g++ compiler. So apparently, `T` is deduced to be an array (instead of a pointer). Is that behavior guaranteed by the standard? I was a little bit surprised, because the following code prints the size of a pointer, and I thought `auto` behaves exactly like template argument deduction?

```
int main()
{
    auto x = "If you timidly approach C++ as just a better C or as an object-oriented language, you are going to miss the point.";
    print_size(x);
    // prints 4
}
```

Comment: Don't now for the former but the latter is not unexpected. String literals ARE arrays, aren't they?

Comment: For anybody reading this who doesn't know: you can't pass arrays by value (they decay to pointers) but you sure can pass a reference to an array. Here, `const T&` becomes a reference to an array and so `sizeof` gives the size of the array.

Comment: Martinho's answer covers the main question.  For is the behavior guaranteed, 14.8.2.1/2: "If `P` is not a reference type: If `A` is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer standard conversion is used in place of `A` for type deduction;..." where `P` is the type of a template function's function parameter which can involve one or more template parameters, and `A` is the type of the expression used in the function call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`auto` behaves exactly<sup>1</sup> like template argument deduction. Exactly like `T`!

Compare this:

```
template<typename T>
void print_size(T x)
{
    std::cout << sizeof(x) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print_size("If you timidly approach C++ as just a better C or as an object-oriented language, you are going to miss the point.");
    // prints 4
    auto x = "If you timidly approach C++ as just a better C or as an object-oriented language, you are going to miss the point.";
    print_size(x);
    // prints 4
}
```

With this:

```
template<typename T>
void print_size(const T& x)
{
    std::cout << sizeof(x) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print_size("If you timidly approach C++ as just a better C or as an object-oriented language, you are going to miss the point.");
    // prints 115
    const auto& x = "If you timidly approach C++ as just a better C or as an object-oriented language, you are going to miss the point.";
    print_size(x);
    // prints 115
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Not quite, but this is not one of the corner cases.

Comment: Stupid me. Thanks for lifting the curtain :)

Comment: Because, of course, you cannot pass a C-style array as a value in C++.

Comment: @Yakk: Indeed, since that would break C compatibility. C didn't have references, so there was no existing behavior to break there.